# I have a video background for my home page,when I open in mobile device instead of video playing,i need to display a image of my choice?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

What extra attribute should I add so that when opened in mobile or small devices ,image appears instead of video?

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately,  this is not a php or rails issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user agent from client on that basis you can replace image or video or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

please replace attribute  using jquery

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('#footer-media-image').attr('src', "images/all-stories-mobile.jpg");
    }
```